# Google map error in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, google-maps, sapui5

I am trying to include google map in sapui5 application.

**index.html**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

I have loaded the file.

in **view.js**

```
        var oGridTiles=new sap.ui.core.HTML({
            content: "<div id='map_canvas' style='width: 300px; height: 200px;'></div>"
            })


oGridTiles.placeAt("content");
```

I have a div with id content in index.html.

Finally in **controller.Js**:

```
 onInit: function() {
         var geocoder;
          var map;


        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom : 15,
            center : latlng,
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas').get(0), myOptions);
        }
```

But in editor its still saying google is undefined. When i run the application the map is not rendering. What is the mistake i am doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously your google maps script is not loaded yet in the `onInit()` event handler.

Better place your google maps initialization code in the control's `onAfterRendering()` event handler.

Comment: I tried it. Its not rendering in onAfterRendering() also

Comment: Got it the issue is the controller is not working for that view. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: That can be anything.. namespace incorrect, different casing, syntax error... what is the error message you get?

Comment: The oninit is only working rendering functions are not working. No error in console.

Comment: ?? that is weird... can you update your question with the onAfterRendering event handler in your controller?

Comment: Thats nice of you. Will put my time on this. If i can't figure it out. Will ask it here as new one :)